# Change the point of rotation of a selected portion of a mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I'm trying to select the arm of a character and rotate it at the shoulder. I want to shift the point the selected vertices to rotates at the shoulder of the character.

Comment: Place the 3D cursor at the desired rotation pivot, then press the `.`(Period) key to rotate about the 3D cursor.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. That will be so useful to me.